# Hold Option in Twilio Application

Tags: twilio

Why twilio not provide a hold option as like their mute option?

It doesn't make sense, to use a API to do this option because it just like the mute option except it needs Hold music to be played during for caller.

Any solution? or update?

Comment: I think this question is best asked to the Twilio team, you can reach them at help at Twilio dot com, I think it would be hard for users here to understand the reasons behind their decision to not have or provide such a function. You can also log a support call in your Twilio portal.

Answer (score 1):

as for a solution, I would understand that an agent is only dealing with a single call at any one time, so having to place a caller on hold, should be pretty simply, you could simply take the call and place it into a conference where you can play the music of your choice. You could use the agent name perhaps and add hold to it to easily get the agent back to the call in the conference, so perhaps creating a conference in such a way, where the agent name is agent1, the conference name could be agent1hold. Once the agent has finished with that which he was busy with when placing the call on hold in the first place, he could simply dial back into the conference. you would need to make sure that you setup the conference correctly so that if the caller has to be placed on hold again, and the agent exits the conference, that the conference is not terminated.

Comment: When we click Hold button, we will redirect the call using REST api and place it in a Conference(<Conference>), now the caller hearing the waitMusic until the agent join the conference. Once a agent joined the Conference now the both caller and agent will speak with each other.
Now, when the agent press the hold button again, we will kick out the agent from the Conference. So currently there is only one participant(caller) only remaining in the conference and this time caller could not hearing any waitMusic.how to play a waitMusic when there is only one participant in the conference.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

Basic hold functionality can be handled via modifying live calls:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

An example in Python where you would use the URL parameter directing the caller to some TwiML to [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) the caller some hold music. You easily give this a try by hosting the TwiML with [Twimlbin](http://twimlbin.com).

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACCOUNT_SID"
auth_token  = "AUTH_TOKEN"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.update("CALL_SID", url="YOUR_TWIMLBIN_URL",
    method="POST")
```

And some examples of working with other scenarios involving [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) can be found on our blog.

1. In Java: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/how-to-warm-transfer-a-call-with-java-and-twilio-voice.html
2. In Python: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/warm-phone-call-transfers-with-python-flask-and-twilio-voice.html